# нужно переместить элемент на N% с помощью margin-top

Tags: html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Главная</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="general">
        <header id="header1">
            <img src="01_one_page.png" id="picture1">
            <nav class="nav1"><pre class="nav2">home       about       work       process       services       testimonials       contact</pre></nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



#general {
    height:5797px;
}
#header1 {
    background:rgb(233,233,233);
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1366px;
    width:100%;
    height:11.5577%;
}
#picture1 {
    margin-left:7.17%;
    margin-top: 2.781%;
}
.nav1 {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    margin-top: 3.29%;
    margin-left:47.8%;
}
.nav2 {
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

есть #picture1 and .nav1, в данном случае мне удалось переместить #picture1 в процентах на ширину 96px и высоту 38px по формуле "Размер элемента в пикселях / Размер родительского элемента в пикселях * 100", где размер элемента (ширина от левого края #header1 до того места, где должна быть картинка) в пикселях был   38px (ну а margin-top == 38px), а размер род. элемента (max-width #header1) был 1366px.

Но с .nav1 не все в порядке, явно видно, что он не там где должен быть, если сравнивать с макетом. 
Считал, учитывая что нужно делить "размер элемента" на ширину родительского элемента, на которую нужно переместить элемент, так как перемещение margin-top/bottom and margin-left/right в процентах совершается относительно ширины родительского элемента

задача: переместить .nav1 на 653px вправо и на 45px вниз относительно #header1, используя margin-left and margin-top со значениями в процентах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы что-то посчитать в css, есть функция calc, почитай про неё, она сама будет тебе в коде вычитать и делить и умножать, чтобы элементы вели себя как-то определённо относительно родит элементов, то нужно задавать позиционирование relative для род и absolut для дочерних, а вообще если ты делаешь навигацию, как я понял, то тег pre это вообще не то. Сделай список, обнули стили и отступы, задай display : flex, и выравнивай